# Displaying graphs and charts in a rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I am creating a web based app for plotting stock data adjusted for things like inflation, GDP, etc...

What gem / tools would you use to take some data and create charts / graphs in a Rails app?

Shawn

Comment: I used Google Charts in the end. Worked great. See CappedIn.com for charts on odds, line movements, picks. These were done with Google charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any gems for this since charts / graphs would be rendered through the browser so it is not concerned with whichever web framework. [Data Driven Documents](http://d3js.org) has some interesting things that it can do and it looks like it does what you need. All you need to do is feed it the right data through your back end technology.

Answer (score 0):

This provides basic and more advanced functionality to integrate charts like pie, bar, line, etc... in your rails app by providing just one line of ruby code...

> http://chartkick.com/
>
> https://github.com/ankane/chartkick